# Comportamento de concatenações de strings em C

Tags: c, string

Por que o seguinte código em C funciona?

```
char *str = "A""B"; /* str = "AB" */
```

---

Porém notei que é apenas em declarações de strings, por exemplo o seguinte não funcionaria:

```
char *a = "A";
char *ab = a "B"; /* Funcionaria se a fosse uma macro */
```

---

Suspeito que funcione porque o compilador considera `"A""B"` como um único bloco de memória e faça a "concatenação" automaticamente.

Em suma gostaria de saber se minha suposição está certa ou é por outro motivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque o compilador do C cola/concatena literais de strings consecutivas.

Por exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    const char *hw = ""
        "Hello"
        " "
        "World" "!" "!" "!";

    printf("%s", hw);
}
```

Produz como saída:

```
Hello World!!!
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/n6qioV)

Entretanto, isso só vale para strings literais. Não funciona com variáveis ou com outras coisas.

Comment: então de certa forma minha suposição estava certa?

Comment: @JonathaGabriel Sim. O compilador faz um tratamento VIP para sequências de literais de strings considerando-as como uma string só.